# What if I select different region for VM than Virtual network?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

Let's assume, I created a new Virtual Network in the Brazil South region and create a new VM with the virtual network but in the South India region. What happens after it was created. Is there any additional cost incurred?

The VM in south India is configured with the same VNet.

Comment: VM in south India configured with same VNet ? or new one?

Comment: @Sajeetharan, Same VNet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be charged based on the number of resources you create. In this case you have one Vnet and 1VM, so your cost will be similar to as below based on the configuration,

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From MS docs:

```
A resource can only be created in a virtual network that exists in the same region and subscription as the resource.
```

So, it is not even possible to create a VM in different region than the VNET itself.

Comment: When I was posting this question, it was possible.